# Why VBA function "split" returns a 2 dimensional array, instead of a 1 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, split

when I use the function *split* to break a string into an array I get 2 different results.

if I type in the string in the code the return is an one dimensional array —array(0), array(1), array(2)

```
values_array = Array(Split("value1, value2", ","))
```

however, if read the value from a cell or something, the return is a two dimensional array — array(0,0), array(0,1), array(0,2)

```
values_array = Array(Split(row.Columns(2).Value, ","))
```

PS. in the line of code above "row" is dim as range

it probably looks stupid, but I tried it this way and it didn't work

```
values_array = Array(Split(Format(row.Columns(2).Value, "@"), ","))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Both `Array(Split("value1, value2", ","))` and `Array(Split(row.Columns(2).Value, ","))` create a two-dimensional array.**

The `Split` function return an array.
The `Array` function take a variable number of parameters and make an array out of them.

So in both cases you are making **an array with one element which is itself an array**.
If you are more comfortable with a picture, here it is

[image: Array of a Split result]

where `a` has been set to `Array(Split("value1, value2", ","))`.

---

It's up to you to know how your program needs to store data, but you may consider removing the call to the `Array` function.